# Custom Floor/Ceiling with Significance on a Time Series data Python

Tags: python, numpy, time-series

I have been working on a project which uses Time Series for its Calculation.

I would want to have the the Floor and Celing of data  (similar to the ones in Excel's FLOOR and CEILING for an entire column

I checked for custom numpy functions, but couldnt see anything which includes significance level

I defined custom functions

```
def ceil(x, s):
    return s * math.ceil(float(x)/s)

def floor(x, s):
    return s * math.floor(float(x)/s)
```

However I cannot use them simultaneously on an entire column

Because of which I need to iterate each row individually:

```
    for i in symbols:
    symbols[i]['PutStrike']=0
    symbols[i]['CallStrike']=0      

    for counter in range(0,len(symbols[0])):
        symbols[i]['PutStrike'][counter]=floor(symbols[i]['FUT'][counter],Strike_Diff[i])
        symbols[i]['CallStrike'][counter]=ceil(symbols[i]['FUT'][counter],Strike_Diff[i])

     return symbols
```

Which of course is not the correct approach along with being time consuming

What I want is something like this:

```
def CalculateIV(symbols):
    for i in symbols:

        symbols[i]['PutStrike']=0
        symbols[i]['CallStrike']=0       
        symbols[i]['PutStrike']=floor(symbols[i]['FUT'],Strike_Diff[i])
        symbols[i]['CallStrike']=ceil(symbols[i]['FUT'],Strike_Diff[i])

    return symbols
```

However when I run, I get:

```
 CalculateIV(abc)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<ipython-input-456-599f9aa19e37>", line 1, in <module>
 CalculateIV(abc)

 File "<ipython-input-452-190c395d86ed>", line 9, in CalculateIV
 symbols[i]['PutStrike']=floor(symbols[i]['FUT'],Strike_Diff[i])

 File "<ipython-input-260-8a88fc57ddf5>", line 2, in floor
 return s * math.floor(float(x)/s)

 File "C:\Users\jay\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line     93, in wrapper
"{0}".format(str(converter)))

 TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

Can some one please suggest an alternative/quicker approach or any library which could ease this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was easier than I thought

I had to use the vectorize function in numpy (np.vectorize)

```
def ceil(x, s):
return s * math.ceil(float(x)/s)

def floor(x, s):
return s * math.floor(float(x)/s)

vfloor=np.vectorize(floor)
vceil=np.vectorize(ceil)
```

Thus these functions are now vectorized.

I can straight away use this to process multiple dataframes within seconds.

```
        def CalculateIV(symbols):
           for i in symbols:

              symbols[i]['PutStrike']=0
              symbols[i]['CallStrike']=0       
              symbols[i]['PutStrike']=vfloor(symbols[i]['FUT'],Strike_Diff[i])
              symbols[i]['CallStrike']=vceil(symbols[i]['FUT'],Strike_Diff[i])

           return symbols
```

If pqr has multiple dataframes in it.

I can just use the below to gather the floor and ceil values

```
output=CalculateIV(pqr)
```